# Why some keyboard events are getting lost in QT?

Tags: qt

On both Windows and MacOS I observed the following behavior:

- User attempts to use a hotkey, which is a combination of two modifiers (Shift, Alt, Ctrl etc) and an alphanumeric key.
- When they do it in a certain order (modifiers first, then alphanumeric) the KeyRelease event for the alphanumeric key never comes.
  This has been tested right in the main loop, so I'm sure there is no other code blocking event propagation.

What can be a fix for that?

Comment: Any chance those combinations are platform specific shortcuts? In such case it makes sense if the are not reaching Qt as they are intercepted by the OS.

Comment: One of the examples is Shift + Command + S on Mac. I don't think it means anything, does it?

Comment: Dunno, I don't have a mac.

Comment: You should post your test so other users can test to reproduce the behavior.

Comment: `Command + S` means [Start up in single-user mode](https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT201255) on a Mac. `Ctrl+S` means Save on most Windows applications.

Comment: Do the press events work ? Are only the release events missing ? If so, do you need the release events. IMO hot keys usually react on the press event I'd say ..

Comment: Press events work, release for modifiers work too (at least in this case), only release for S doesn't come. Unfortunately, this causes problems in the application logic. I will try to make a test app to repro this.